# How can I get my messages to appear in my textbox for my chat application c# socket programming tcp

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, chat

I have gone through several tutorials on socket programming, and I've gotten none of them to work for me, except for this one. I was able to get the server to receive messages from multiple clients on different computers. Now I can't figure out how to make the messages post to my textbox. I would appreciate any help as I am quite new to this.

This is the server code:

```
namespace server_tutorial
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("555.555.5.55");

        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip, 8080);
        TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);

        try
        {
            server.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Server started...");



        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.Read();
        }

        while (true)
        {

            client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

            foreach(byte b in receivedBuffer)
            {
                if (b.Equals(00))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                    msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine(msg.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

and here is the client code:

```
namespace client_tutorial
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string serverIP = "555.555.5.55";
    int port = 8080;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIP, port);

        int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(message.Text);

        byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];

        sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message.Text);

        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

        stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);

        stream.Close();
        client.Close();

    }
}
```

I know this is a very simple to some, but I would appreciate any help.

Comment: so ... where is your textbox?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that, the textbox is just called textbox1 right now. And it is located on the client

Comment: and i assume message is another textbox where you type in the message.... do you want to push that message from that box to textbox1 or do you mean to receive a message from the server or another client and put that to textbox1?

Comment: I would like the message box to be able to send the message to the server infor the client to be able to get the message from the server into textbox1 so everyone connected to the server using the client will be able to see the messages

Comment: in this case there is a problem with your approach: your server is incapable of handling multiple clients, and your clients do not hold a connection to the server ... both things are requirements for what you want to do ...maybe have a look here ... https://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2012/09/21/communicating-through-sockets/

Comment: Thanks but I have been able to connect to the server from multiple clients from different computers at the same time and it displays the messages on the console server just fine what I have to set up networkstream?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138379/discussion-between-jdwee-and-darksquirrel42).

Comment: waited for you in chat ... 2 AM here ... maybe tomorrow